# not able to use query properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to run following query in CodeIgniter but it is not returning the correct output
According to the query, one of the condition is that if the value of $supplier_id is not matched then no result should be displayed. However, it is displaying all the result no matter what the value of supplier_id is. Can anyone please help me in correcting this query

```
public function get_onboarded_detail()
    {
        $supplier_id = 40;
        $query = $this->db->select('*')

          ->from('job')
          ->join('job_workforce', 'job_workforce.job_id = job.id', 'Right')
          ->where('job_workforce.supplier_id',$supplier_id)
          ->where('job_workforce.status','onboarded')
          ->or_where('job_workforce.status','job_offer')
          ->or_where('job_workforce.status','offer_accepted_by_client')
          ->or_where('job_workforce.status','offer_accepted_by_supplier')
          ->get();
          $res =  $query->result();          
    }
```

Comment: try to echo the query `echo $this->db->last_query();` `exit();` before `$res =  $query->result(); `

Comment: @Shreyas Achar I am getting this o/p =  SELECT * FROM `job` RIGHT JOIN `job_workforce` ON `job_workforce`.`job_id` = `job`.`id` WHERE `job_workforce`.`supplier_id` = 40 AND `job_workforce`.`status` = 'onboarded' OR `job_workforce`.`status` = 'job_offer' OR `job_workforce`.`status` = 'offer_accepted_by_client' OR `job_workforce`.`status` = 'offer_accepted_by_supplier'

Comment: If you put `$supplier_id = ''` what is the output you are getting?

Comment: @ShreyasAchar it gives this o/p SELECT * FROM `job` RIGHT JOIN `job_workforce` ON `job_workforce`.`job_id` = `job`.`id` WHERE `job_workforce`.`supplier_id` = '' AND `job_workforce`.`status` = 'onboarded' OR `job_workforce`.`status` = 'job_offer' OR `job_workforce`.`status` = 'offer_accepted_by_client' OR `job_workforce`.`status` = 'offer_accepted_by_supplier'

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the CI stuff, and instead focus on getting a working raw query. From there we can talk about how to rewrite it in CI's syntax. If you want to pursue that approach, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: you can use `group_start()` and `group_end()` if you want specific condition to group and get results.

Comment: @anuj arora can you please tell how can i use group_start() and group_end()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem with your where condition because its contain "OR" condition, so whatever your supplier_id system will return true result. see below example:-

Your current where condition:-

```
WHERE job_workforce.supplier_id = 40 AND job_workforce.status = 'onboarded' OR job_workforce.status = 'job_offer' OR job_workforce.status = 'offer_accepted_by_client' OR job_workforce.status = 'offer_accepted_by_supplier'
```

It should be:-

```
WHERE job_workforce.supplier_id = 40 AND (job_workforce.status = 'onboarded' OR job_workforce.status = 'job_offer' OR job_workforce.status = 'offer_accepted_by_client' OR job_workforce.status = 'offer_accepted_by_supplier')
```

To make a correction using codeigniter please use:

```
public function get_onboarded_detail()
{
    $supplier_id = 40;
    $query = $this->db->select('*')

      ->from('job')
      ->join('job_workforce', 'job_workforce.job_id = job.id', 'Right')
      ->where("job_workforce.supplier_id = $supplier_id AND (job_workforce.status = 'onboarded' OR job_workforce.status = 'job_offer' OR job_workforce.status = 'offer_accepted_by_client' OR job_workforce.status = 'offer_accepted_by_supplier')");

      ->get();
      $res =  $query->result();          
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I don't believe, this is marked as correct answer and also got 2 likes. As it is not using codeigniter functions, instead writing custom conditions. There are provisions for everything.

Comment: Note that in MySQL, this can be abbreviated to `WHERE jw.supplier_id = 40 
  AND jw.status IN ('onboarded','job_offer','offer_accepted_by_client','offer_accepted_by_supplier')`

Answer (score 0):

> According to the query, one of the condition is that if the value of $supplier_id is not matched then no result should be displayed. However, it is displaying all the result no matter what the value of supplier_id is.

If you are using **OR** between conditions, even if any one condition is true it will return output. Use **AND** if you want to filter your result with all the conditions provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use the codeigniter grouping of where conditions. You can make groups accordingly.

```
public function get_onboarded_detail() {

    $supplier_id = 40;
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                  ->from('job')
                  ->join('job_workforce', 'job_workforce.job_id = job.id', 'Right')
                  ->group_start()
                      ->where('job_workforce.supplier_id',$supplier_id)
                      ->where('job_workforce.status','onboarded')
                  ->group_end()
                  ->group_start()
                      ->or_where('job_workforce.status','job_offer')
                      ->or_where('job_workforce.status','offer_accepted_by_client')
                      ->or_where('job_workforce.status','offer_accepted_by_supplier')
                  ->group_end()
                  ->get();
         $res =  $query->result();          
}
```